# Почему это предложение не является ССП?

Tags: ссп

> Ветер, казавшийся слабым, здесь был весьма силен и порывист, мост
> качало, и волны с шумом ударялись в берег.

Почему это предложение не является ССП?

Comment: Потому что здесь два типа связи, а не один.

Answer (score 1):

Находим простые предложения:
***(1)** Ветер, казавшийся слабым, здесь был весьма силен **и** порывист, **(2)** мост качало, **(3)** **и** волны с шумом ударялись в берег.*

Определяем основы: ветер был силен, порывист; мост качало; волны ударялись.

Сочинительные союзы могут связывать не только части сложносочинённого предложения, но и однородные члены. Первый союз "и" соединяет составные именные сказуемые (именная часть выражена краткими прилагательными) *был силен* и [был] *порывист* (то есть первое предложение осложнено однородными сказуемыми и причастным оборотом).

• Между первым и вторым предложениями — бессоюзная связь.

• Второй союз "и" соединяет третье простое предложение с первыми двумя — эта связь сочинительная.

Так что данное предложение является сложной синтаксической конструкцией с бессоюзной и союзной сочинительной связью.

Полное предложение Л. Н. Толстого из "Севастопольских рассказов" имеется в [*упражнении 70*](https://studfile.net/preview/3544128/page:13/) (здесь его трактуют как сложносочиненное предложение (?)).

[Составное именное сказуемое](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/704-15_sostavnoe_imennoe_skazuemoe.html)
[Сложные предложения. Типы сложных предложений](https://siblec.ru/lingvistika/russkij-yazyk/russkij-yazyk/slozhnye-predlozheniya-tipy-slozhnykh-predlozhenij)

Comment: Чего это? А БСП вы куда дели? Здесь смешанный тип (и бессоюзная связь, и союзная).

Comment: Ужас! http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/455

Comment: Но у типов связи же нет иерархии, их не расставляют по значимости. Всего 4 типа: ССП, СПП, БСП, смешанный тип (в скобках указываются виды связи). Четвёртый идёт наравне с остальными.

Comment: Думаю, не зря вопрос, почему не является ССП.

Comment: Конечно, не зря... Хорошо! Сейчас изничтожу все лишние рассуждения, оставлю только конкретику. И ужас исчезнет.